# Fast algorithm to detect laptop lid closed from images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have an application which captures images periodcally.
Sometimes, when the laptop lid is closed, it is still capturing images, and the images look like this:
[image]

I don't want them, so I am searching for an algorithm to detect the images like that. I've tried some methods like brightness detection and histogram, but they were inaccurate in some scene.
There is always an main object in front of the camera, so there is no need for the algorithm to differentiate the lid is closed, the camera is covered up or the laptop is placed in a completely dark room.